# Unloading a driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

Is it possible to unload a driver which was loaded at boot time. If yes, how can this be done?

---

System is Windows XP. I tried `net stop` but I got "`The requested control is not valid for this service` "

The driver is a kernel mode driver which is loaded by a service so I cannot uninstall it from device manager.

Any ideas how to unload the driver?

Comment: You need to include information about which operating system.

Comment: mcnamara - could you provide some information on what operating system you are attempting to unload drivers from?  That may help others to provide a more useful answer.  Also, a description of the type of device that you are attempting to unload would also be useful.

Comment: If it's a WinXP system, why on earth is this question tagged "Linux"?

Comment: hi, i suppose it's a little bit off topic now but have you ever found out how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use [`modprobe`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) like so:

```
modprobe -r [module name]
```

On Windows it can be done using the [Device Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283658).

On Mac you can use the developer tool [`kextunload`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kextunload.8.html)

Comment: It's Windows XP dude.

Comment: yes, linux is an operating system

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can also enter

```
> net stop [drivername]
```

on the commandline (or Start > Run) to unload a driver.

Comment: Doesn't `net stop` only apply to services?

Comment: EvilChookie: No, both `net stop` and `sc stop` can control both services and drivers.

Comment: it's a dirty little secret they only tell you when they chain you to the desk and force you to write drivers.